# Email quota not increased on new Google Workspace account

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace

I have signed up for a new workspace account with 2 mail accounts ($12 per month each), but the email quota seems not to have increased.

```
function checkQuota(){
  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log("Mails remaining "+quotaLeft)
}
```

When I run this function it's showing me 100 units but it should be 1500. I don't remember any delay the last time I set up new gmails on my old Google Worspace account.

The admin panel is showing the invoice is paid.

Is there a delay? If not...ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently signed up for a Google Workspace account this means that you are probably still stuck with the trial limits. As stated [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en#zippy=%2Climits-increase-for-paid-accounts):

> ### Gmail sending limits in Google Workspace
>
> After you convert from a free trial account to a paid subscription, your account sending limits automatically increase when both of the following are true:
>
> Your domain has cumulatively paid at least USD 100 (or equivalent)
> At least 60 days have passed since reaching that payment threshold
> If you bought your domain from Google, the cost to increase your limits is the cost of your domain plus US 100.

This applies for any Google service such as Google Calendar, Gmail, etc. So basically you need to meet both requirements to bypass the trial limits. If I am not mistaken the policies were changed some months ago, that is why it was easier to get out of the trial limits before.

Because of the trial limits you will have the same limits as a consumer account. You can see the full list [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).